# asp.net mvc checkbox + insert data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a question. I have a 3 models (Person, RegisteredAddress and AddressCorrespondence) The RegisterAddress and AddressCorrespondence are exactly the same table (with the same names of columns). The Person model is :

```
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName{ get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDate{ get; set; }
    public bool TheSameAddress{ get; set; }
```

The model of Addresses

```
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Street{ get; set; }
    public int Number{ get; set; }
    public string Code{ get; set; }
    public string State{ get; set; }
    public string City{ get; set; }
    public int Person_Id { get; set; }
```

And then I have a 3 views. Evry view are a form to fill which respons evry model. In first view we can mark the checkBox value of "TheSameAddress" property.
What I want to do is: When the user mark this checkbox then i'd like to open only a view with a RegisteredAddress but i'd like to save the same data into 
AddressCorrespondence table.
It's mean that when the checkbox is marked then should be only shown a 2nd form (after 1st) but the 3rd view/form couln't be display but in the database the date should be save.
Does anybody havy any idea how can i make it/solve my problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Option 1

if I understood you can do it like :

in the view :
*Person Register View* 
form design is as you want, you can hide or show the third form if the checkbox is enabled or not

```html
@model WebApplication2.Models.Person
@{ 
    ViewBag.Title = "Register Person";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="col-lg-12"><br /></div>
        <label>FirstName</label>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.FirstName)
    <div class="col-lg-12"><br /></div>
        <label>LastName</label>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LastName )
    <div class="col-lg-12"><br /></div>
       <label>The Same Address?</label>
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m=>m.TheSameAddress)
    <div class="col-lg-12"><br /></div>
    <label>City</label>
    <input type="text" name="City"id="City" />
    <div class="col-lg-12"><br /></div>
    <label>Code</label>
    <input type="text" name="Code" id="Code" />
    <div class="col-lg-12"><br /></div>
    <label>Number</label>
    <input type="number" name="Number" id="Number" />
    <div class="col-lg-12"><br /></div>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />

}
```

Controller

compare if the `checkbox` is true adds the data to  `RegisteredAddress` and `AddressCorrespondence` else just add data to RegisteredAddress

```html
        public ActionResult CreatePeople()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult CreatePeople(Person person,string city,string code , int number)
        {
            if (person.TheSameAddress == true )
            {
                var newperson = new Person
                {
                    FirstName = person.FirstName,
                    LastName = person.LastName,
                     BirthDate= DateTime.Now,
                    TheSameAddress=person.TheSameAddress                                                
                };
                db.person.Add(newperson);
                db.SaveChanges();
                var newRegisterAdress = new RegisteredAddress
                {
                    City = city,
                    Code = code,
                    Number = number,
                    Person = newperson
                };
                db.RegisteredAddress.Add(newRegisterAdress);
                db.SaveChanges();
                var newAdressCorrsp = new AddressCorrespondence
                {
                    City = city,
                    Code = code,
                    Number = number,
                    Person = newperson
                };
                db.AddressCorrespondence.Add(newAdressCorrsp);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            else
            {
                var newperson = new Person
                {
                    FirstName = person.FirstName,
                    LastName = person.LastName,
                    BirthDate = DateTime.Now,
                    TheSameAddress=person.TheSameAddress
                };
                db.person.Add(newperson);
                var newRegisterAdress = new RegisteredAddress
                {
                    City = city,
                    Code = code,
                    Number = number,
                    Person = newperson
                };
                db.RegisteredAddress.Add(newRegisterAdress);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            return View();
        }
```

it is an idea of how you can do can be adapted to the three views if you want

if you want to asign the data in other view

### Option 2

register the person first and asign the adress from index view , Index =People

like: 
 IndexView

```html
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication2.Models.Person>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "People";
}
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            <label>Name</label>
        </th>
        <th>
            <label>LastName</label>
        </th>
        <th>
            <label>BirthDate</label>
        </th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName )
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName )
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BirthDate)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Add Adress", "CreateAdress", new { Id_Person = item.ID }, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "btn btn-primary btn-xs" })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

Controller

```html
        public ActionResult CreateAdress(int Id_Person )
        {
            ViewBag.PersonId = Id_Person;
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult CreateAdress(RegisteredAddress ra ,int Id_Person)
        {
            var personf = db.person.Find(Id_Person);
            if (personf.TheSameAddress == true)
            {
                var newRegisterAdress = new RegisteredAddress
                {
                    City = ra.City ,
                    Code = ra.Code,
                    Number = ra.Number,
                    Person = personf
                };
                db.RegisteredAddress.Add(newRegisterAdress);
                db.SaveChanges();
                var newAdressCorrsp = new AddressCorrespondence
                {
                    City = ra.City,
                    Code = ra.Code,
                    Number = ra.Number,
                    Person = personf
                };
                db.AddressCorrespondence.Add(newAdressCorrsp);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            else
            {
                var newRegisterAdress = new RegisteredAddress
                {
                    City = ra.City,
                    Code = ra.Code,
                    Number = ra.Number,
                    Person = personf
                };
                db.RegisteredAddress.Add(newRegisterAdress);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            return RedirectToAction("People");
        }
```

I leave a link with the project [here](https://mega.nz/#!4EE3jIDJ!tMZBkj9_rG8MkjfoCAvsBD9Y-Txv1PafNJZdAJATqHI)